# Search event not firing in @ng-select/ng-select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

```
<ng-select class="custom" [items]="ingredientsSearchList" bindLabel="name" bindValue="value" placeholder="Search ingredients/your products" (search)="onSearch($event)" loadingText="Searching">
            </ng-select>
```

is my code. But its weird that all output events like blur, etc are fired except search event. As a work around I have used (keyup) event to trigger the same. Is there any mistake I am doing to not trigger search event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are using v2.8.0. This version supports the search event.